# Port negotiation issues, IP Radio tower

Tags: port, cable, power-over-ethernet, ubiquiti, interference

Got a ubiquity IP radio on a tower.  One side of the link negotiates 1G but the other side has issues.  It will negotiate 100Mb after a reboot every now and again (very random) but mainly sits at 10Mb. I can iperf the link and saturate it on 100Mb for extended periods (minutes) but eventually it dies and renegs back to 10Mb. Sometimes the link drops altogether and won't negotiate at all.

So after replacing all the UTP running to the switch with STP, putting a grounded switch in, and everything I can to block interference in the doghouse, I think I will be forced to start looking at the copper coming down from the tower. I don't think it unlikely that maybe the installers were hard on the line and work hardened a couple pair of conductors or untwisted them exposing them to interference. I'm new to interference troubleshooting so bare with me.

My main question I was hoping to get answered: is there a way to run a cable verifier on the line going up the tower, with it being plugged in to the ubiquity gear (which requires a PoE injector)? How far can I get in troubleshooting this without having a tower hand come climb it?

Any ideas or suggestions on diagnosing this issue would really help.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, We miss some detail, as it’s a site to site link via radio ? as such the link itself is open to interferance.

Comment: @yagmoth555 It is a site to site link, AF11-FX IP Radio.  I don't follow you, do you mean interference across the microwave could propagate into the copper line?

Comment: No, I just wanted to be sure the 10mb link was detected between the radio and the switch, not the radio link itself, wasnt sure

Comment: For your question itself if it’s the swich / radio link in problem, some network cable analyser can do a basic check with just one side plugged, but you migh miss debug information. Like I know fluke do some good gear for testing, the microscan from fluke I have can do a basic check, but it wont show broke pair without the injector on the other side in exemple

Comment: Yes it's the switch/radio link I'm having problems with.  I can't get two sides plugged into a verifier unless I get someone to climb the tower.  I guess I'll just have to have someone climb it and test the cable.  Was just hoping there was another way.

Comment: If someone climb it, maybe make it go with a new wire too, just in case.

Comment: @yagmoth555 that would be smart! :)